# How to Add ScrollView to GLSurfaceview in Opengl ES2.0 in Android

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, scrollview, scrollviewer, android-scrollview

I am developing an Auto-cad App in OpenGLES2.0 in Android.
I want to add the panning  functionality.

That's how I achieve this pan function:
[Pan Functionality -- just drag the GLSurfaceview to top, bottom,left and right side using touch event].

I need to add a Scrollable View in GLSurfaceview in android.
When I try to add a scroll view in GLSurfaceView, it will not work.
Then, also I tried to add GLSurfaceview in to the ScrollView.
This method also does not work.

Please suggest me some sample code.

Comment: Hi Everyone, i am looking for pan functionality in Opengl es2.0 in android.Here i need to Pan the GLSurfaceview.thats why, i am tried to add scrollview instead using matrix method.i need to move the GLsurfaceview scene not object. please anyone give some sample code to accomplish my task.

Comment: Hi, my sample code here...http://www.mediafire.com/download/55lp59gdq78a3q3/LineDraw_Test.zip

Comment: What is the purpose of adding a ScrollView to the SurfaceView? Maybe we can find another solution if you explain the purpose. If you want a pannable OpenGL "view" you should implement it manually or look for examples in OpenGL: https://goo.gl/MFSUks

Comment: I agree with @C.d., I implemented a 'ScrollView' in my OpenGL ES 2.0 app manually.